# how to print a list as a matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist

I want to print a list as a matrix. For example my list have 9 elements, I want to print this list as 3x3 matrix.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h','i']
```

I want to print this list as 3x3:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Comment: What if your list had 10 elements?

Comment: @Nick my list will always have square number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

If your list always has a square number of elements, you can compute the square root of the length and iterate that many times over parts of the list:

```
import math

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h','i']

size = int(math.sqrt(len(l)))
for i in range(size):
    print(*l[i*size:i*size+size])
```

Output:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```